# При взятии данных из firebase и передаче их на новый Storyboard , данные прогружаются позже чем новый storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Проблема в том что storyboard раньше грузится чем я передаю данные пытался через.GCD но не вышло.
Плюс словил баг непонятный с firebase , отправил код знакомоу , при запуске и регестрации пользователя данные на сервер не отправляются , но в туже секунду я отправлял данные на сервер, в чем может быть проблема

LoginViewController - где проходит авторизация

```
@IBAction func didTapLoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {(result,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ НАЙДЕТ !")
            }else{
                print("Авторизация прошла успешно")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                print("------------------USER-ID-----------------")
                print("USER ID          \(userID)")
                print("------------------USER-ID-----------------")
                var userName = userID
                APIManager.shared.getPost(collection: "users", docName: "\(userName)", completion: {doc in
                    guard doc != nil else{return}
                    var name = doc?.name
                    var email = doc?.email
                    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
                    print("User NAME: \(name)")
                    guard let userPageViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:"UserPageViewController" ) as? UserPageViewController else {return}
                    userPageViewController.getUserName = name
                    print("Data transit")
                        }
                    )}
                }
            
            }
```

UserPageController - Куда данные должны перейти

```
import UIKit

class UserPageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private  weak var userAvatarIg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private  weak var userNameLB:UILabel!
    public var getUserName:String!
    public var dateForLabel:String!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userAvatarIg.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarIg.frame.size.width/2
        userAvatarIg.clipsToBounds = true
        print("_----------------------------------------")
        print("\(userNameLB)")
        userNameLB.text = getUserName
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

}
```

APIManager - Где хранится логика взятия данных

```
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    // MARK: - Config
    private func configFB()->Firestore{
        var db:Firestore!
        let setting = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = setting
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        return db
    }
    
    // MARK: - Get info from db
    
    func getPost(collection:String, docName:String, completion:@escaping(Document?)-> Void){
        let db = configFB()
        db.collection(collection).document(docName).getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard error == nil else {completion(nil); return }
            let doc = Document(name: document?.get("name") as! String, email: document?.get("email") as! String)
            completion(doc)
        }
    }
```

ТЕРМИНАЛ :

```
    2021-01-14 00:59:24.176895+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141050] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.7.3.0 started
2021-01-14 00:59:24.177109+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141050] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ----------)
2021-01-14 00:59:24.531536+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141093] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2021-01-14 00:59:24.775996+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141051] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2021-01-14 00:59:24.776981+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141051] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2021-01-14 00:59:36.945828+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2141051] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ НАЙДЕТ !
ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ НАЙДЕТ !
ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ НАЙДЕТ !
2021-01-14 01:00:08.249113+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2139887] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC9Client_Vk25GroupsTableViewController in Interface Builder file.
_----------------------------------------
Optional(<UILabel: 0x7faca6f67a10; frame = (120 64; 86 21); text = 'User Name'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x6000020dca00>>)
----------VIEW-WILL-LAYOUT-SUBVIEWS----------
                nil
----------VIEW-WILL-LAYOUT-SUBVIEWS----------
2021-01-14 01:00:08.373820+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2139887] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d2120 UIButton:0x7faca6d57550'\U0414\U0420\U0423\U0417\U042c\U042f'.centerY == UILabel:0x7faca6d572e0.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d21c0 V:|-(5)-[UIButton:0x7faca6d57550'\U0414\U0420\U0423\U0417\U042c\U042f']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7faca6f5b260 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d2030 V:[UIButton:0x7faca6d57550'\U0414\U0420\U0423\U0417\U042c\U042f']-(4)-[UICollectionView:0x7faca80e1400]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1ef0 V:[UILabel:0x7faca6d572e0]-(9)-[UICollectionView:0x7faca80e1400]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1f40 V:|-(9)-[UILabel:0x7faca6d572e0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7faca6f5b260 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1ef0 V:[UILabel:0x7faca6d572e0]-(9)-[UICollectionView:0x7faca80e1400]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
----------VIEW-WILL-LAYOUT-SUBVIEWS----------
                Optional(<UILabel: 0x7faca6f67a10; frame = (120 64; 86 21); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x6000020dca00>>)
----------VIEW-WILL-LAYOUT-SUBVIEWS----------
Document successfully written!
Авторизация прошла успешно
------------------USER-ID-----------------
USER ID          HSxXdlAkWjVyFCbJ1vf10rt3qHj1
------------------USER-ID-----------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
User NAME: Optional("anastas")
Data transit
2021-01-14 01:03:07.794819+0300 Client_Vk[41888:2145339] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в коде нет строчки, где вы презентуете свой сториборд, значит, вы презентуете его где-то в другом месте (например, через segue), а в коде присваиваете проперти getUserName другому экземпляру сториборда, который, в свою очередь, никак не показываете. Соответственно, уберите предыдущую презентацию сторибода и сделайте present(userPageViewController, ...) после userPageViewController.getUserName = name. Тогда будет показан нужный сториборд с установленным значением getUserName.